# Split on newline 80 Chars

Tags: bash

i have in a txt file long text

```
example:
https://pastebin.com/MnbR0Vdh

it should look like that:
https://pastebin.com/ASKHKrS6
```

how can split the text after 80 Charater to new line?

```
so can see, but not written
grep '.\{80\}' test.txt
sed -i "s/\(.\{3\}\)/\1\n--/" test.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please re-post you samples of input and output as it is NOT clear as of now.

Comment: Specifically, don't link to an external source; make the question self-contained by adding a representative bit of input to the question itself.

Comment: It looks like you don't want to just wrap at 80 characters, but insert `... ` at the beginning of every single new line, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

```
fold file
```

or

```
sed 's/.\{80\}/&\n/g' file
```

---

You say you want to wrap the text at 80 chars but your example output says different, maybe you're looking for sth like this???

```
sed 's/\(^\.\.\. \)\?.\{75\}/&\n... /g' file
```